# How to beat NSMutableArray performance with Swift (beta) Array?

Tags: performance, cocoa-touch, swift, ios8

In Swift, I'm trying to build a large collection of items. When creating elements in CoreData on-the-go, this is very speedy. However when trying to keep an index to those items, creating an array Swift has a large performance impact. The code below is a benchmark between NSMutableArray and Swift's Array. When ran in the iOS Simulator, the Swift Array is around 8x slower. Why is this, can it be improved, or should it improve over the as Apple releases new builds of Xcode/Swift?

Code:

```
var start: NSDate
var time: NSTimeInterval
var batch = 1000000
var rate: Double

var oArr = NSMutableArray(capacity: batch)
start = NSDate()
for i in 1..batch {
    oArr.addObject(i)
}
time = -start.timeIntervalSinceNow
rate = Double(batch) / Double(time)
println("NSMutableArray \(batch) appends in \(time) sec: \(rate)/sec")

var sArr = Int[]()
start = NSDate()
for i in 1..batch {
    sArr += i
}
time = -start.timeIntervalSinceNow
rate = Double(batch) / Double(time)
println("Array<Int>     \(batch) appends in \(time) sec: \(rate)/sec")
```

Output in simulator (beta 2) 794%:

```
NSMutableArray 1000000 appends in 1.17320102453232 sec: 852368.843096295/sec
Array<Int>     1000000 appends in 9.31138801574707 sec: 107395.374170729/sec
```

Output in simulator (beta 3):

```
NSMutableArray 1000000 appends in 0.71416300535202 sec: 1400240.55083487/sec
Array<Int>     1000000 appends in 5.00839000940323 sec: 199664.961818569/sec
```

Output on iPhone 5 (beta 3 on iOS 7.1):

```
NSMutableArray 1000000 appends in 8.79256194829941 sec: 113732.494110367/sec
Array<Int>     1000000 appends in 55.6573320031166 sec: 17967.084730975/sec
```

Comment: wait until apple fixed Swift Array, then try again.

Comment: There is nothing to be fixed... Just compile the swift version without runtime checks (as Objc does).

Comment: "When ran in the iOS Simulator, the Swift Array is around 8x slower." Do not performance test in the simulator. It does not reflect real-world results. Either run on a device or run in an OS X (command line) app.

Comment: @JackLawrence I'm not running the benchmark so I can compare numbers with other systems; it's just the observation that `Array` is *a lot* slower than NSArray. Whether that's observed in the Simulator, iOS device or OS X app; I don't care.

Comment: Right, but the comment still applies. The Array implementation is probably not optimized for i386/arm sim because there's no reason to do so.

Comment: @JackLawrence see my updates. As expected, the performance difference on the device is similarly to the simulator.

Comment: @bouke You certainly built this "benchmark" with optimizations enabled, did you?

Comment: Chris Lattner said several times that they will tune performance in the coming Betas. I wouldn't worry until we have 1.0 release to compare too. If you follow him on the Apple Developer Forums he spoke about this several times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

with Xcode beta-3, with a console program on a MacBook Pro 2 GHz Intel Core i7, I get these numbers with the original test (also fixed syntax due to minor grammar changes):

**Debug (-O0):**

```
NSMutableArray 1000000 appends in 0.782136023044586 sec: 1278549.9843203/sec
Array<Int>     1000000 appends in 5.56463801860809 sec: 179706.208500177/sec
```

**Release (-Os):**

```
NSMutableArray 1000000 appends in 0.14977502822876 sec: 6676680.43081684/sec
Array<Int>     1000000 appends in 0.124498963356018 sec: 8032195.3937913/sec
```

**Release (-Ofast):**

```
NSMutableArray 1000000 appends in 0.151567995548248 sec: 6597698.91646863/sec
Array<Int>     1000000 appends in 0.122538030147552 sec: 8160731.80543105/sec
```

Comment: on beta5, iOS8, iPhone 5S with -Os:`NSMutableArray 100000 appends in 0.0127469897270203 sec: 7844989.45566939/sec
[Int] 100000 appends in 0.053788959980011 sec: 1859117.55938694/sec` so still 5x difference :/

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem fair that you're telling the `NSMutableArray` how much space it needs to allocate right up front but making the Swift array re-allocate itself with every single append. This makes the Swift version stupid fast, although it's kind of unfair in the other direction:

```
var sArr = Array<Int>(count: batch, repeatedValue: 0)
start = NSDate()
for i in 0..batch {
    sArr[i] = i
}
```

**Edit:** It looks like `NSMutableArray` doesn't actually use the capacity you provide to speed itself up, so maybe never mind?

Comment: It's fair as I want both implementations as fast as possible. NSMutableArray provides arguments to set an initial capacity. However your suggestion for creating an Array with initial values is also interesting. It's not quite the same as initial capacity, but shows that Array could be performant as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Swift optimizer is very much a work in progress. Even between b1 and b3 I've seen a little benchmark program go from taking 3s (compiled at -O) to taking 0.2s. Remember to try -O and -Ofast, keep trying it with each beta, and file bugs about unusually or unexpectedly slow things. It should get a lot better over time :)

Answer (score 1):

I've done some tests on my old iPhone 4 with XCode 6.3.1 and found that Array is much faster than NSMutableArray.

Debug mode

```
NSMutableArray  1000000 appends in 8.11677902936935 sec: 123201.579885525/sec
Array1<Int>     1000000 appends in 3.9488559961319 sec: 253237.900034732/sec
Array2<Int>     1000000 appends in 2.59551799297333 sec: 385279.548324162/sec
```

Release mode

```
NSMutableArray  1000000 appends in 5.76798897981644 sec: 173370.650238625/sec
Array1<Int>     1000000 appends in 0.0752439498901367 sec: 13290105.0710402/sec
Array2<Int>     1000000 appends in 0.0505729913711548 sec: 19773400.2456174/sec
```

Where Array1 = [Int] (), Array2 = [Int?](count: batch, repeatedValue: nil)

And for Array1 I used array.append(i) instead of "+=" which can make it much faster.