# Slow Swift Arrays and Strings performance

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, performance, swift

Here is two pretty similar `Levenshtein Distance algorithms`.

`Swift` implementation:
https://gist.github.com/bgreenlee/52d93a1d8fa1b8c1f38b

And `Objective-C` implementation:
https://gist.github.com/boratlibre/1593632

The `swift` one is dramatically slower then `ObjC` implementation 
I've send couple of hours to make it faster but... It seems like `Swift` arrays and `Strings` manipulation are not as fast as `objC`.

On 2000 `random Strings` calculations `Swift` implementation is about 100(!!!) times slower then `ObjC`.

Honestly speaking, I've got no idea what could be wrong, coz even this part of swift

```
func levenshtein(aStr: String, bStr: String) -> Int {
// create character arrays
let a = Array(aStr)
let b = Array(bStr)
...
```

is few times slower then whole algorithm in `Objective C`

Is anyone knows how to speedup `swift` calculations?

Thank you in advance!

**Append**

After all suggested improvements swift code looks like this.
And it is **4 times slower then ObjC** in release configuration.

```
import Foundation
class Array2D {
    var cols:Int, rows:Int
    var matrix:UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>


    init(cols:Int, rows:Int) {
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        matrix = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(malloc(UInt(cols * rows) * UInt(sizeof(Int))))
        for i in 0...cols*rows {
            matrix[i] = 0
        }

    }

    subscript(col:Int, row:Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return matrix[cols * row + col] as Int
        }
        set {
            matrix[cols*row+col] = newValue
        }
    }

    func colCount() -> Int {
        return self.cols
    }

    func rowCount() -> Int {
        return self.rows
    }
}

extension String {
    func levenshteinDistanceFromStringSwift(comparingString: NSString) -> Int {
        let aStr = self
        let bStr = comparingString

//        let a = Array(aStr.unicodeScalars)
//        let b = Array(bStr.unicodeScalars)

        let a:NSString = aStr
        let b:NSString = bStr

        var dist = Array2D(cols: a.length + 1, rows: b.length + 1)



        for i in 1...a.length {
            dist[i, 0] = i
        }

        for j in 1...b.length {
            dist[0, j] = j
        }

        for i in 1...a.length {
            for j in 1...b.length {
                if a.characterAtIndex(i-1) == b.characterAtIndex(j-1) {
                    dist[i, j] = dist[i-1, j-1]  // noop
                } else {
                    dist[i, j] = min(
                        dist[i-1, j] + 1,  // deletion
                        dist[i, j-1] + 1,  // insertion
                        dist[i-1, j-1] + 1  // substitution
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        return dist[a.length, b.length]

    }
    func levenshteinDistanceFromStringObjC(comparingString: String) -> Int {
        let aStr = self
        let bStr = comparingString
        //It is really strange, but I should link Objective-C coz dramatic slow swift performance
        return aStr.compareWithWord(bStr, matchGain: 0, missingCost: 1)

    }

}
```

malloc?? NSString?? and at the end 4 times speed decrease? Is anybody needs swift anymore?

Comment: Other users confirms that Swift arrays is really slow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567429/how-to-beat-nsmutablearray-performance-with-swift-beta-array

Right now Swift is not Beta. So it looks pretty strange for me.

Comment: It has been 2 years, this code is still slow, noway to fix?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why the Swift code is slower than the Objective-C code.
I made a very simple test case by comparing two fixed strings 100 times.

- Objective-C code: 0.026 seconds
- Swift code: 3.14 seconds

The first reason is that a Swift `Character` represents an "extended grapheme cluster",
which can contain several Unicode code points (e.g. "flags"). This makes the 
decomposition of a string into characters slow. On the other hand, Objective-C
`NSString` stores the strings as a sequence of UTF-16 code points.

If you replace

```
let a = Array(aStr)
let b = Array(bStr)
```

by

```
let a = Array(aStr.utf16)
let b = Array(bStr.utf16)
```

so that the Swift code works on UTF-16 sequences as well then the time goes down
to 1.88 seconds.

The allocation of the 2-dimensional array is also slow. It is faster to allocate
a single one-dimensional array. I found a simple `Array2D` class here:
http://blog.trolieb.com/trouble-multidimensional-arrays-swift/

```
class Array2D {
    var cols:Int, rows:Int
    var matrix: [Int]


    init(cols:Int, rows:Int) {
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        matrix = Array(count:cols*rows, repeatedValue:0)
    }

    subscript(col:Int, row:Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return matrix[cols * row + col]
        }
        set {
            matrix[cols*row+col] = newValue
        }
    }

    func colCount() -> Int {
        return self.cols
    }

    func rowCount() -> Int {
        return self.rows
    }
}
```

Using that class in your code

```
func levenshtein(aStr: String, bStr: String) -> Int {
    let a = Array(aStr.utf16)
    let b = Array(bStr.utf16)

    var dist = Array2D(cols: a.count + 1, rows: b.count + 1)

    for i in 1...a.count {
        dist[i, 0] = i
    }

    for j in 1...b.count {
        dist[0, j] = j
    }

    for i in 1...a.count {
        for j in 1...b.count {
            if a[i-1] == b[j-1] {
                dist[i, j] = dist[i-1, j-1]  // noop
            } else {
                dist[i, j] = min(
                    dist[i-1, j] + 1,  // deletion
                    dist[i, j-1] + 1,  // insertion
                    dist[i-1, j-1] + 1  // substitution
                )
            }
        }
    }

    return dist[a.count, b.count]
}
```

the time in the test case goes down to 0.84 seconds.

The last bottleneck that I found in the Swift code is the `min()` function.
The Swift library has a built-in `min()` function which is faster. So just removing
the custom function from the Swift code reduces the time for the test case to
0.04 seconds, which is almost as good as the Objective-C version.

*Addendum:* Using Unicode scalars seems to be even slightly faster:

```
let a = Array(aStr.unicodeScalars)
let b = Array(bStr.unicodeScalars)
```

and has the advantage that it works correctly with surrogate pairs such
as Emojis.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed comment!

Unfortunately after all suggested modification I can not see improvement as you mentioned.
My figures are:
Swift Levenstaining of 10000 cityes rate 589/sec
ObjC Levenstaining of 10000 cityes rate 106281/sec
I was testing using Swift command line project template.
May be I need some additional setting to be done?

Comment: By the way, to get even this figure I've reverted Array2D to use NSMutableArray which is much faster then Swift Arrays.

Comment: @Alexey: Have you switched the build configuration from "Debug" to "Release" to get optimized code? – You could also try a plain malloc'ed array (as in the ObjC code) with `var dist = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>(malloc((a.count + 1) * (b.count + 1) * UInt(sizeof(Int))))`.

Comment: After release configuration I have Swift Levenstaining of 1000 cityes rate 4259/sec
ObjC Levenstaining of 1000 cityes rate 142328/sec

Comment: After mallocing Array2D the figures are
Swift Levenstaining of 10000 cityes rate 28468/sec
ObjC Levenstaining of 10000 cityes rate 130751/sec

It is 7 times slower. Anyway it is not 100 :-)

Comment: let a:NSString = aStr gives a bit speedup. Now swift version is 4 times slower in release configuration. Who needs SWIFT after that?!

Comment: @Alexey: I found that the built-in variadic min() function is still a bottleneck. Using `func min3(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) -> Int { return min(min(a, c), min(b, c)) }` instead makes it considerably faster in my test case.

Comment: You might get an increase by using a local `let` instead of calling `x.count` repeatedly.