# NSRange or Range<String.Index> - what is faster for algorithm calculating identity between two strings in swift3?

Tags: string, range, swift3, nsrange

If we have two variants of the same algorithm (for instance calculating identity between two strings) working with `NSRange` (where string will be casting as NSString) or `Range<String.Index>`, which variant of the algorithm will perform faster in swift3 ?

**Update**

So, I have tested 4 variants for my code in playground using

```
let date_start = NSDate()
//code
print("\(-date_start.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
```

20.3485659956932 sec Swift 2.2 for code using `Range<String.Index>`

31.3328449726105 sec Swift 2.2 for code using `NSRange`

12.3670780062675 sec   Swift 3 for code using `Range<String.Index>`

15.9888380169868 sec  Swift 3  for code using  `NSRange`

Swift3 has improved performance in comparison with Swift2.2 - almost two times. `Range<String.Index>` is little bit better than `NSRange`

Comment: @Eric D Maybe somebody can give the explanation based on the nature of NSRange and Range<String.Index> in swift3

Comment: @VYT: generally, Swift is _fast_ (C++ backend), and you shouldn't worry about performance until a profiler tells you to. In case you're really interested, your best answer would be some profiling/testing of the two methods yourself, using some computationally heavy test cases.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990394/slow-swift-arrays-and-strings-performance is an example where working on the UTF-16 view (and that is essentially what NSString uses) turned out to be much faster.

Comment: @VYT good addition with the test cases, but all performance tests should be performed in an actual project rather than a playground, to allow possible cleverness of the compiler (some platground code can be hideously slow, whereas it runs fast in an actual project).