# Complexity of String operations in Swift

Tags: swift, string, utf-8, time-complexity, swift3

I have print()-style function which takes an array of Strings and concatenates utf8 representations of these strings to utf8 char array. So, I need to approximate the size of the array to preallocate it.

The question is:

1) What is the complexity of creating different views on a String? (`string.characters`, `string.utf8`).

2) What is the complexity of counting the entities in these views once the view is constructed? (`string.characters.count`, `string.utf8.count`)

Which one would be faster: summing `string.utf8.count`-s or `string.characters.count * 4`? I understand that not every character is 4 bytes, but for approximating the output array size this is probably good enough.

UPD: Some benchmarks:

```
let s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."

for _ in 0...1000000 { c += s.characters.count }
for _ in 0...1000000 { c += s.utf8.count }
for _ in 0...1000000 { c += s.utf16.count }

s.characters.count: 5.55736202001572 seconds.
s.unicodeScalars.count: 2.87764900922775 seconds.
s.utf8.count: 0.901157021522522 seconds.
s.utf16.count: 0.214971005916595 seconds.
```

Unicode string:

```
let s = "☁ ☂ ☃ ☄ ★ ☆ ☇ ☈ ☉ ☊ ☋ ☌ ☍ ☎ ☏ ☐ ☑ ☒ ☓ ☚ ☛ ☜ ☝ ☞ ☟☠ ☡ ☢ ☣ ☤ ☥ ☦ ☧ ☨ ☩ ☪ ☫ ☬ ☭ ☮ ☯ ☰ ☱ ☲ ☳ ☴ ☵ ☶ ☷ ☸ ☹ ☺ ☻ ☼ ☽ ☾ ☿ ♀ ♁ ♂ ♃ ♄ ♅ ♆ ♇ ♈ ♉ ♊ ♋ ♌ ♍ ♎ ♏ ♐ ♑ ♒ ♓ ♔ ♕ ♖ ♗ ♘ ♙ ♚ ♛ ♜ ♝ ♞ ♟ ♠ ♡ ♢ ♣ ♤ ♥ ♦ ♧ ♨ ♩ ♪ ♫ ♬ ♭ ♮ ♯"

s.characters.count: 9.24248600006104 seconds.
s.unicodeScalars.count: 4.10243701934814 seconds.
s.utf8.count: 2.78127604722977 seconds.
s.utf16.count: 0.210725963115692 seconds.
```

Even longer unicode string:

```
let s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Лорем ипсум долор сит амет 123456789               ☺                                                                    ☁ ☂ ☃ ☄ ★ ☆ ☇ ☈ ☉ ☊ ☋ ☌ ☍ ☎ ☏ ☐ ☑ ☒ ☓ ☚ ☛ ☜ ☝ ☞ ☟☠ ☡ ☢ ☣ ☤ ☥ ☦ ☧ ☨ ☩ ☪ ☫ ☬ ☭ ☮ ☯ ☰ ☱ ☲ ☳ ☴ ☵ ☶ ☷ ☸ ☹ ☺ ☻ ☼ ☽ ☾ ☿ ♀ ♁ ♂ ♃ ♄ ♅ ♆ ♇ ♈ ♉ ♊ ♋ ♌ ♍ ♎ ♏ ♐ ♑ ♒ ♓ ♔ ♕ ♖ ♗ ♘ ♙ ♚ ♛ ♜ ♝ ♞ ♟ ♠ ♡ ♢ ♣ ♤ ♥ ♦ ♧ ♨ ♩ ♪ ♫ ♬ ♭ ♮ ♯"

s.characters.count: 21.852580010891 seconds.
s.unicodeScalars.count: 9.216412961483 seconds.
s.utf8.count: 7.34296900033951 seconds.
s.utf16.count: 0.21273398399353 seconds.
```

I've also tested on large data sets (`s * 100000` times) - `s.utf16.count` maintains the same performance.

So, it appears that only s.utf16.count is O(1). Others are O(n) with `characters` being the slowest one.

Comment: why would you need to approximate the size of the array?

Comment: All *"Which one would be faster"* questions should contain at least an attempt where you measured the difference yourself. That would also give you an idea  if the time spent in that part of your app is relevant at all.

Comment: @martin-r Agreed, I'll do the benchmarking and will update the question.  I wanted to know which one of them is O(1) and which one is O(n).

Comment: My *guess* would be that counting the `utf16` or `unicodeScalars` view are the fastest, at least that is what I observed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990394/slow-swift-arrays-and-strings-performance.

Comment: Your results are what I expected. But note that your test string is ASCII-only. It should include letters from other languages, special characters, symbols, emojis, flags ...

Comment: @martin-r I've added unicodeScalars to the tests, it also appears to be slow, only utf16 is a direct representation. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction! Could you create an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: The code you want to look at is https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringCore.swift. It currently stores strings internally as either UTF-16 or ASCII. However, it may also wrap an NSString or CFString, so you need to check what formats CFString can hold internally (http://opensource.apple.com//source/CF/CF-855.11/CFString.c) There is of course no promise of these implementations; it is a private implementation detail. Swift could choose (possibly in the future; possibly now) to store String other ways if not initialized by a StaticString as you do in all your tests.

Comment: @Zmey: Rob's comment is the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to preallocate. You can do something like (approximately - on my phone, can't check syntax)

```
Array(stringArray.joinWithSeparator("").characters.utf8)
```

I'm not sure of the syntax to get UTF8 from individual characters-if you leave that off, this would be an array of 'characters'. If you leave off the conversion to Array this is a sequence.

To answer your question, strings are natively UTF16, and astring.characters.count is very fast. Be careful of what you count if any of the multi-grapheme characters could be present.

Comment: According to docs Character represents an extended grapheme cluster. If internal String storage is UTF16, `astring.characters.count` probably involves iterating the entire string and should be slow?

Comment: Nope, the count is maintained directly. There is a great article on how swift stores strings at https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-06-why-is-swifts-string-api-so-hard.html

Comment: I've added benchmark data to the question, it seems characters is slowest of all the views.

Comment: Good point. I should have suggested Array(stringArray.joinWithSeparator("").utf8)