# Levenshtein distance in Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, levenshtein-distance, rosetta-code

I'm using a tutorial from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Swift) to calculate Levenshtein distance. It seems their code is in Swift2 so I get  this error `Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Int]' and 'Repeated<String.CharacterView>'` when doing this: `var cur = [i + 2] + empty` where `let empty = repeatElement(s, count: 0)`. How can I go about this?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990394/slow-swift-arrays-and-strings-performance is an implementation which should require only minor modifications for Swift 3.

Comment: Thanks, worked but would still love to use their(Rosetta) method since it seems shorter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There were a couple of changes to make.

- The construction of the Array empty.
- enumerate() is now enumerated()
- successor() doesn't exist anymore so I replaced it with +1

So the function is now

**Swift 4:**

```
func levDis(_ w1: String, _ w2: String) -> Int {
    let empty = [Int](repeating:0, count: w2.count)
    var last = [Int](0...w2.count)

    for (i, char1) in w1.enumerated() {
        var cur = [i + 1] + empty
        for (j, char2) in w2.enumerated() {
            cur[j + 1] = char1 == char2 ? last[j] : min(last[j], last[j + 1], cur[j]) + 1
        }
        last = cur
    }
    return last.last!
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
func levDis(w1: String, w2: String) -> Int {

    let (t, s) = (w1.characters, w2.characters)

    let empty = Array<Int>(repeating:0, count: s.count)
    var last = [Int](0...s.count)

    for (i, tLett) in t.enumerated() {
        var cur = [i + 1] + empty
        for (j, sLett) in s.enumerated() {
            cur[j + 1] = tLett == sLett ? last[j] : min(last[j], last[j + 1], cur[j])+1
        }
        last = cur
    }
    return last.last!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated and improved answer to Swift 4, based on @Spads answer.

```
extension String {
    func levenshteinDistanceScore(to string: String, ignoreCase: Bool = true, trimWhiteSpacesAndNewLines: Bool = true) -> Float {

        var firstString = self
        var secondString = string   

        if ignoreCase {
            firstString = firstString.lowercased()
            secondString = secondString.lowercased()
        }
        if trimWhiteSpacesAndNewLines {
            firstString = firstString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            secondString = secondString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }

        let empty = [Int](repeating:0, count: secondString.count)
        var last = [Int](0...secondString.count)

        for (i, tLett) in firstString.enumerated() {
            var cur = [i + 1] + empty
            for (j, sLett) in secondString.enumerated() {
                cur[j + 1] = tLett == sLett ? last[j] : Swift.min(last[j], last[j + 1], cur[j])+1
            }
            last = cur
        }

        // maximum string length between the two
        let lowestScore = max(firstString.count, secondString.count)

        if let validDistance = last.last {
            return  1 - (Float(validDistance) / Float(lowestScore))
        }

        return 0.0
    }
}

infix operator =~
func =~(string: String, otherString: String) -> Bool {
    return string.levenshteinDistanceScore(to: otherString) >= 0.85
}
```

Comment: What does this actually calculate? As far as I know the Levenshtein Distance is an Int, not a float.

Comment: This makes sense to me neither.

Comment: IDK if this still works, but baasically this should return a value between 0 a and 1, 0 being the strings are totally different and 1 the strings are the same; it returns how similar two strings are.

Answer (score 2):

Since @Daniel Illescas answer is not working, here is working version with `Int` return type and with assert.

```
extension String {

    func levenshteinDistance(to string: String, ignoreCase: Bool = true, trimWhiteSpacesAndNewLines: Bool = true) -> Int {
        
        var firstString = self
        var secondString = string
        
        if ignoreCase {
            firstString = firstString.lowercased()
            secondString = secondString.lowercased()
        }
        
        if trimWhiteSpacesAndNewLines {
            firstString = firstString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            secondString = secondString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }
        
        let empty = [Int](repeating: 0, count: secondString.count)
        var last = [Int](0...secondString.count)
        
        for (i, tLett) in firstString.enumerated() {
            var cur = [i + 1] + empty
            for (j, sLett) in secondString.enumerated() {
                cur[j + 1] = tLett == sLett ? last[j] : Swift.min(last[j], last[j + 1], cur[j]) + 1
            }
            
            last = cur
        }
        
        if let validDistance = last.last {
            return validDistance
        }
        
        assertionFailure()
        return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func ~=(string: String, otherString: String) -> Bool {
    return string.levenshteinDistanceScore(to: otherString) >= 0.85 
}
```

Comment: This is the correct operator Overloading for levenshteinDistanceScore String Extension. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48976605/9991497