# Matching text to keywords in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, search, match, keyword

Let's say I'm parsing a document and am trying to find `Test©/Testing© Keyword Finder` by taking some keywords and matching them to the aforementioned string.

If I were using a document where each block of text is separate and clearly defined so that there wouldn't be any confusion as to what words were connected in a sentence/title, is there a way in Swift to compare such a block of words with keywords to find a match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Levenshtein distance, aka edit distance, is a metric for measuring the difference between two strings. The implementation of it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44102415/4110172):

```
func levenshteinDist(test: String, key: String) -> Int {
    let empty = Array<Int>(repeating:0, count: key.count)
    var last = [Int](0...key.count)

    for (i, testLetter) in test.enumerated() {
        var cur = [i + 1] + empty
        for (j, keyLetter) in key.enumerated() {
            cur[j + 1] = testLetter == keyLetter ? last[j] : min(last[j], last[j + 1], cur[j]) + 1
        }
        last = cur
    }
    return last.last!
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
let test1 = "Test©/Testing© Keyword Finder"
let test2 = "Test© Word Finder"
let test3 = "Number Categorizer"
let test4 = "Alphabet in Order"

let key = "Test Testing Keyword"

print(levenshteinDist(test: test1, key: key)) // 10
print(levenshteinDist(test: test2, key: key)) // 14
print(levenshteinDist(test: test3, key: key)) // 18
print(levenshteinDist(test: test4, key: key)) // 15
print(levenshteinDist(test: key, key: key)) // 0
```

As you can see, `levensthlindist(test: key, key: key)` outputs `0`, since the strings are same. Also, the minimum output is `10` and it corresponds to the expected test string.